# How to implement "Number of times that Foo has a Bar associated only with that Foo"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My scenario is like this. I have a table like

```
 Foo | Bar | ... |
==================
  A  |  1  | ... |
  A  |  2  | ... |
  A  |  2  | ... |  
  B  |  2  | ... |
  B  |  2  | ... |
  B  |  1  | ... |
  C  |  1  | ... |     
  C  |  1  | ... |  
  C  |  1  | ... |  
  D  |  2  | ... |  
  D  |  1  | ... | 
  D  |  1  | ... |
```

and what I want a query that does, in English,

> "For each `Bar`, get the number of `Foo`s that are associated with that
>   `Bar` only"

So the resulting table would be like

```
Bar | Count |
=============
 1  |   1   |
 2  |   0   |
```

**Explanation:**

You can see that the rows

```
  C  |  1  | ... |     
  C  |  1  | ... |  
  C  |  1  | ... |
```

are an example where a given `Foo` is associated with only one `Bar`, but there are no other such examples.

This is a generic version of real-life scenario I'm facing and I can't figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  You only care about foos with only one bar.  So that is these:

```
select foo, min(bar) as bar
from t
group by foo
having min(bar) = max(bar)
```

Then, if you want the number of bars . . . let me assume you have a list of bars:

```
select b.bar, coalesce(bb.cnt, 0)
from bars b left join
     (select bar, count(*) as cnt
      from (select foo, min(bar) as bar
            from t
            group by foo
           ) fb
      group by bar
     ) bb
     on b.bar = bb.bar;
```

If you don't have a list of bars, then use `(select distinct bar from t) bar` instead of `bar` in the `from` clause.

I think this will also work:

```
select bar,
       count(distinct case when minbar = maxbar then foo end) as numfoos
from (select t.*, min(bar) over (partition by foo) as minbar,
             max(bar) over (partition by foo) as maxbar
      from t
     ) t
group by bar;
```

Comment: Shoot. Now I have to convert this to LINQ haha.